# Paypal Express Checkout (Ruby on rails) not return PAYMENTID, only PAYERID and TOKEN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I have read about Paypal Express Checkout doc and follow the same steps to get a good result...

When I send the token with the URL:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/checkoutnow?token=TOKEN

And the Customer accept the pay, Paypal redirect him to my return_url with PAYERID and TOKEN params, but not PAYMENTID.

In the next step Paypal doc said that we need PAYMENTID to continue the proccess and execute the PAYMENT.

Did you have this problem.

This is the link I follow:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/#rest-integration-steps

Thanks!